# Invoke-vmscript diskextend issue

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

When attempting to run my script I got the following the error message.

Script :

```
$extenddisk= @"


 
$letter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive | select -ExpandProperty Drive
Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '$letter'" ) -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'} 

$newdisk = @(get-disk | Where-Object partitionstyle -eq 'raw')

for($i = 0; $i -lt $newdisk.Count ; $i++)

{

 

  $disknum = $newdisk[$i].Number

  $dl = get-Disk $disknum |

  Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru |

  New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize

  Format-Volume -driveletter $dl.Driveletter -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false

 

}

 

"@


Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $extenddisk -VM $vm -GuestCredential $VMLocalCredential -ScriptType Powershell
```

Error:

```
WARNING: The version of VMware Tools on VM 'Hostname' is out of date and may cause Invoke-VMScript to work improperly.

 

 

 

 

 

ScriptOutput

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|  At line:9 char:27

|  + for( = 0;  -lt .Count ; ++)

|  +                           ~

|  Missing expression after unary operator '++'.

|      + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

|      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

|  

| 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATE :

```
$extenddisk= @'


 
`$letter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive | select -ExpandProperty Drive
Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '`$letter'" ) -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'}

[string[]] `$DiskArray = [char[]] (68..89)
`$DiskArrayIndex = 0

`$Disks = Get-Disk |  Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' 

Foreach  (`$D in `$Disks) {
        `$D | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | 
        New-Partition -DriveLetter `$DiskArray[`$DiskArrayIndex++] -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | 
        Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:`$false

        
}

 

'@


Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $extenddisk -VM $row.ServerName -GuestCredential $VMLocalCredential -ScriptType Powershell
```

Comment: this looks like the variables (e.g. $i) are replace with their empty values, before the script is transfered and executed (I am not a powershell-expert...)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `"` (double-quotes) with here-strings, PowerShell will attempt to expand all variables and enclosed subexpressions in the content of it. Use `'` (single-quotes) instead:

```bsh
$extenddisk = @'
...
'@
```

Comment: Thanks again. BTW , Is there any issue my inside script ? Or What do you recomended ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, or which disks/volumes are acessible on your system or whether the script is currently doing what you're expecting it to do - I can't see your screen :) I'm assuming you received an(other) error after making the quote-change?

Comment: :) Actually I currently have a build script I supply to customers for building new servers then  run inside the guest OS (through Invoke-VMScript) a script to discover this new disk, format it and assign a drive letter. Repeat for the number of harddisks required.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my comment under Mathias , but my reputation is too small.. anyway. @Arbelac , Mathias is correct here. you should change your here string to @' '@ And it will be just find for you usage. It would not be fine if you would be doing some 'extra stuff' on your side, before it enters the VM inside teh invoke-vmscript, but in this case i see that you are just pass the stript to VM to execute inside, nothing special, therefore dont use the @" "@ like as mentioned all the $stuff will get translated to value, so it ruins your script. You just want to pass the whole script to the VM so no need for @" "@. Everything should work.

Comment: thanks btw  I have updated my script.  is there any missing inside my script ? Also I have used backtick for some variables.

Comment: Hi There, since you switched to the @' '@  it is not treated literaly as it is, meaning you have to undo the backticks you have issued there. I suggest, you take the initial code, don't change the inside of the code with backticks, just change the @"  "@  to @' '@ and this should be enough

Comment: I am assuming you missed my last update script with UPDATE: header. Actually , like you said , I am using  @' '@.  do you have a chance to look again? thanks

Comment: Hi, i did not miss your update. My reply was in regards to your update. Let me know if there is anything not clear. You have use your example from your original post, but replace double quotes  with single qoutes for @. In your update strimg you used the correct quotes, but you are escaping $ for example, and you are not supposed to do it. Please do what i suggested in earlier comment.